# How can I return multiple row values into one cursor variable in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor

I have a package in oracle that contains one stored procedure.  It takes a date as a input and a number as input, and outputs the data into a ref_cursor.  The purpose of the stored procedure is to extract all of the "winning numbers" that correspond to a certain input date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE GETWINNINGNUMBERSBYDATEPKG IS

TYPE lotgwndate_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;     
PROCEDURE GetWinningNumbersDATE (lg_wndate IN date, lg_wnwgid IN number, lg_ref OUT 
lotgwndate_ref_cursor); 

END GETWINNINGNUMBERSBYDATEPKG;
```

This is the package body.  Again, the purpose here is to extract all of the "winning numbers" that correspond to a certain date and "gameid" number.  Then, I want to pair the "winning numbers" with the "game name" and "drawing date".  (This is to extract records from lottery drawings)

```
  PROCEDURE GetWinningNumbersDATE (lg_wndate IN date, lg_wnwgid IN number, lg_ref OUT    
  lotgwndate_ref_cursor) IS
   BEGIN
    OPEN lg_ref FOR
      SELECT a.GAMENAME, b.DRAWINGDATE, c.BALLNUMBER
        FROM GAMEDETAILS a
          INNER JOIN WINNINGRECORDS b
            on a.GAMEDETAILSID = b.GAMEDETAILSID 
              INNER JOIN WINNINGBALLS c
                on b.WINNINGRECORDSID = c.WINNINGRECORDSID


      WHERE b.DRAWINGDATE = lg_wndate
      AND a.GAMEDETAILSID = lg_wnwgid;

END GetWinningNumbersDATE;

END GETWINNINGNUMBERSBYDATEPKG;
```

Here is the call procedure.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON size 100000
DECLARE 
  v_cursor               LOTTERYGAMEPKG.lotgwndate_ref_cursor;
  v_gamename             GAMEDETAILS.gamename%type;
  v_drawingdate          WINNINGRECORDS.drawingdate%type;
  v_ballnumber           WINNINGBALLS.ballnumber%type;
BEGIN
  GETWINNINGNUMBERSBYDATEPKG.GetWinningNumbersDATE(lg_wndate =>    
TO_DATE('06/08/2014','dd/mm/yyyy'), lg_wnwgid => '4', /*date/gamedetailsid #(1-4)*/
                          lg_ref => v_cursor);
LOOP                             
  FETCH v_cursor
    INTO  v_gamename, v_drawingdate, v_ballnumber;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
    (v_gamename || ',' || v_drawingdate || ',' || v_ballnumber);
END LOOP;
 END;
```

This works, and returns:

```
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,10
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,11
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,15
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,16
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,21
```

However, I want it to return

```
NorthstarCash,06-AUG-14,10,11,15,16,21
```

Are there any ways to do this?  I have looked at many other questions but none are addressing the same issue as mine.  ORACLE 11g

Comment: I believe the question you posted does not address the call procedure part of my question.  It only addresses the select statement.  I am trying to figure out how to put the agg string result into my call procedure statement.

Comment: unfortunately, the `FETCH` you expect, actually has to be written by you to append the numbers and by using temp variables... Oracle has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not aware of the syntax to accomplish this.  Perhaps you could direct me to a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Oracle 11g`, just modify your `SELECT` query using [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm)

```
PROCEDURE GetWinningNumbersDATE (lg_wndate IN date, lg_wnwgid IN number, lg_ref OUT    
  lotgwndate_ref_cursor) IS
   BEGIN
    OPEN lg_ref FOR
      SELECT a.GAMENAME, b.DRAWINGDATE, LISTAGG(c.BALLNUMBER,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.BALLNUMBER) AS BALLNUMBER
        FROM GAMEDETAILS a
          INNER JOIN WINNINGRECORDS b
            on a.GAMEDETAILSID = b.GAMEDETAILSID 
              INNER JOIN WINNINGBALLS c
                on b.WINNINGRECORDSID = c.WINNINGRECORDSID  
        WHERE b.DRAWINGDATE = lg_wndate
      AND a.GAMEDETAILSID = lg_wnwgid
     GROUP BY a.GAMENAME, b.DRAWINGDATE;

END GetWinningNumbersDATE;
```

And the caller, has to be modified like below.

```
v_ballnumber           VARCHAR2(4000);
```

Comment: @MatheswaranRavisankar When I make the changes you have suggested and run the call procedure I get `ORA-01722 invalid number`.  Is there a way to tell the call procedure to expect a string to come into the variable?

Comment: Problem is, for the `FETCH INTO` variable(_v_ballnumber_) you used `%TYPE` which refers a `NUMBER` column. Try making it `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been trying to figure this out for a long time!